# Problem with cell selection on a dynamic Grid (Javascript / HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I am new into Javascript and I am trying some basic stuff but I came across this problem.
So the concept is to build a dynamic grid and a color picker tool. You can change the cells (squares) of the grid by clicking on them (after selecting your color) and by pressing the clear button the grid "restarts".

So picking a color and clicking does the job (although this.style.backgroundColor doesn't seem like the best of choices) but I can't seem to be able to recolor(clear) the whole grid.

Every cell that I have clicked will keep the color it already has.

Where am I short thinking this?

```js
const c = document.getElementById("grid");
for (let i = 0; i < 500; i += 20) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 500; j += 20) {
    let r = document.createElement("div");
    r.style.left = `${i}px`;
    r.style.top = `${j}px`;
    r.classList.add("square");
    r.onclick = onClickCell;
    c.appendChild(r);
  }
}

function onClickCell() {
  const rgbaColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
  this.style.backgroundColor = rgbaColor;
}

function clear() {
  const gridStartingColor = `rgba(231,231, 231, 222)`;
  //for visual help, replace with gridStartingColor
  c.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
}

document.getElementById("initialize").onclick = clear;
```

```css
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, avenir next, avenir,
    segoe ui, helvetica neue, helvetica, Ubuntu, roboto, noto, arial,
    sans-serif;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(231, 231, 222);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}
.square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.square.clicked {
  background: red;
}

#controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
button {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div id="controls">
    <div>
      Select color: <input type="color" id="color" value="#f6b73c" />
    </div>
    <button id="initialize">Clear!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're creating a grid of 25 x 25 `div` elements, each of which has zero height, an undefined width (so full width of parent), and no content.  Might want to at least set at least the height (, probably the width), and a background color (or something)

Comment: Should I add my CSS as well?

Comment: If your CSS helps you to create an [mcve], then yes - because your question is incomplete/off-topic without it.  Click the "edit" link just below your question, find and edit the "snipet".  Put the CSS in the "CSS" window.

Comment: Sorry for having to edit my code. Trying my best, this is my first time here

Comment: You might want to re-think the absolute positioning on your grid, since it's overlaying your controls.  Maybe an absolute parent with "display" and "controls" children, then grid elements relative to "display" and color picker/buttons that are relative to "controls"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be setting the background color of the grid container itself, rather than its child cells. You can loop through all the `<div>` elements inside the grid and set each `backgroundColor` to "transparent.

I also converted the grid to a flexbox.

```js
const c = document.getElementById("grid");

function onClickCell() {
  const rgbaColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
  this.style.backgroundColor = rgbaColor;
}

function clear() {
  var ds = c.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (i = 0; i < ds.length; i++) {
    ds[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 500; i += 20) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 100; j += 20) {
    let r = document.createElement("div");
    r.classList.add("square");
    r.onclick = onClickCell;
    c.appendChild(r);
  }
}

document.getElementById("initialize").onclick = clear;
```

```css
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(231, 231, 222);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

button {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div id="controls">
    <div>
      Select color: <input type="color" id="color" value="#f6b73c" />
    </div>
    <button id="initialize">Clear!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah... obviously does the trick. Thanks for pointing it out and for the fast and easy solution!

Comment: @AdaptOvercome it's good to "vote up" an answer (or a question) that you found valuable by clicking the arrows at the left.

Comment: @Tibrogargan tried but since I am a new user, I have restrictions, for now at least. 
Thank you both again!